# How to install the Courier font in RStudio for ggplot2

Tags: r, rstudio

After the update of my OS, fonts disappeared in my Rstudio, and in particular **Courier** I need for ggolot2.

To solve the problem I installed:

```
library(extrafont)
```

and then:

```
font_import()
```

Now I have several fonts, but they are mostly unpopular. For example:

```
fonts()
"aakar" "Abyssinica SIL"  "Ani" "AnjaliOldLipi" "Chilanka"  "DejaVu Sans"            
"DejaVu Sans Mono" "DejaVu Serif" "Droid Sans Fallback" "Dyuthi"
```

How to install the Courier font I need??

I run:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- R version 3.4.4
- RStudio Version 1.2.5033

Comment: I use `R 3.6.2` and `RStudio 1.2.5.001`. After `font_import()`, `fonts()` shows 199 fonts including "Courier New".

Answer (score 0):

Just add the style into your yaml definitions in your .Rmd file like this:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    css: style.css
---

This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code.
```

Then create a `style.css` file in the same folder and paste this code:

```
body{
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 16pt;
}
```

Then reknit it, It will work.

If the Courier font is not in your Ubuntu system you can install it via [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15495/add-microsoft-core-fonts-to-ubuntu/)